# SwiftUI Text replacement not working by default on TextField view

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, swiftui

I'm unable to find an answer on stackoverflow, reddit, or Apple Dev Docs for this. I'm using a standard textfield in swiftui, and the text replacement settings (Settings > General > Keyboard > Text Replacement) aren't working in any of my textfields throughout my app (like when you type 'omw' and it expands to 'on my way'.

Here's one attempt at a TextField with some settings:

```
            TextField("Email",text: $email)
            .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
            .textContentType(.emailAddress)
            .disableAutocorrection(false)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

From my understanding this is a very basic usage of TextField in SwiftUI. How do I enable this feature of iOS to work in my app?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: you're right - iOS 13/Xcode 11 bug fixed in iOS 14. Thank you!